# On the generalization of recursive transposition cipher to strings of arbitrary length

Tags: c

I'm coding a recursive transposition ciphering algorithm in order to refresh some of my plain C skills. As you might be more familiar with the columnar transposition cipher, the recursive one works this way, assuming some plaintext `str` as input:

- `If strlen(str) <=2 : encrypt(str) == str`
- `else : encrypt(str) == encrypt(reversed_first_half_of_str) + encrypt(reversed_second_half_of_str)`

Here's my attempt to cipher plaintext of any length with this algorihtm.

```
void encrypt(char string[], size_t length) {
    int i, rs_bound;
    int mid = floor((double)length / 2.0);
    char left_substr[mid], right_substr[length - mid];

    if (length <= 2) {
        if (length > 0) {
            write_ciphertext(string);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Reverse the first half of the string
    for (i = 0; i < mid; ++i) {
        left_substr[i] = string[mid - i - 1];
    }
    encrypt(left_substr, mid);

    // Reverse the second half of the string
    if ((length - mid) % 2 == 0) {
        rs_bound = mid;
    }
    else {
        rs_bound = mid + 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rs_bound; ++i) {
        right_substr[i] = string[length - i -1];
    }
    encrypt(right_substr, length - mid);

}
```

Given the plaintext `123456789`, it yields the output `3412¬ºþ89575¬ºþ` instead of the correct one, `341289576`. Also, given the plaintext `12345678`, it yields the output `412ÿ7856ÿ` instead of the correct one `341289576`. When I replace the `rs_bound` with `mid`, I get correct outputs for inputs of even length (like the `12345678`) and when I replace it with `mid + 1`, I get the correct output for odd even strings (like the `123456789`).

Note that, for obvious reasons, the `left_substr` has always even length. The only substring that must handle inputs of arbitrary length is the `right_substr`.

Can someone help me generalize the way the `right_substr` handles inputs of both odd and even length correctly?

EDIT: Here's my implementation of `reverse_string`, as per Johnny's suggestion.

```
char* reverse_string(char *str, size_t length)
{
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *revsubstr = malloc(length);
    // Get the substring to be reversed from the whole string.
    memcpy(revsubstr, str, length);

    // "Mark" the two ends of the substring to be reversed.
    char* start = revsubstr;
    char* end = revsubstr + length - 1;
    // Reverse it
    for( ; start < end; ++start, --end) {
        char s = *start, e = *end;
        *start = e;
        *end = s;
    }

    return revsubstr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking finding the mid point. It is just:

```
int mid = length / 2;
```

Your code might be easier to follow if you create a helper function to reverse a string:

```
// Do an in-place reversal of the string. Returns the input string.
char * reverse_string(char *string, size_t length)
{
     for (int l = 0, r = length - 1; l < r; l++, r--) {
        char tmp = string[l];
        string[l] = string[r];
        string[r] = tmp;
     }
     return string;
}
```

Also, I don't see any need for any extra arrays if you do the reversal in-place. Then your code becomes exactly what is described in the problem description.

```
void encrypt(char string[], size_t length)
{
    if (length <= 2) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = length / 2;
    
    // Reverse then encrypt first half
    encrypt(reverse_string(string, mid), mid);
    // Reverse then encrypt second half
    encrypt(reverse_string(&string[mid], length - mid), length - mid);
}
```

I tested this with:

```
int main(void) {
    char num[] = "123456789";
    encrypt(num, strlen(num));
    printf("%s\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
341289576
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, as the first call of `encrypt ` returns back the full `string` which its first half reversed and the second half intact, I need to allocate memory inside the `reverse_string` to return only the reversed substring of the `string`. Kindly check my implementation of `reverse_string` if you'd like (added in my question).

Comment: @Kapoios The reverse function should do an in-place reversal - meaning the changes are made to the original string. See updated answer.